# Building a base for my christmas tree

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to build a Christmas tree with a user inputted triangular top and a rectangular base, but I'm currently stuck while building the base. The specifications are as follows: The triangle starts with a single * and increases the amount of * on each row by a total of 2 per line, such that the final row is 2(n)-1 with n being the inputted height of the triangle. The height of the rectangle (stump) underneath the tree is equal to 1 plus (1/5)n and the width of the stump is 1/3n however if the result of 1/3n is an even integer, add 1 to the total stump width. (i.e the stump width is always an odd number.)
Here's what i have so far, the triangular part of the tree is fine, but the rectangle is a mess.

```
public class xmasTree {

    public static final int TREE_MAXIMUM = 20;
    public static final int TREE_MINIMUM = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //User introduction 
        System.out.println("This program prints a \"Christmas\" tree. You "
            + "choose how big the tree will be (within reason);

        // prompt for and get user input
        System.out.println("How tall should the top of the tree be?");
        int treeHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (treeHeight < TREE_MINIMUM || TREE_MAXIMUM < treeHeight) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid size.  I can only do trees "
                + "from 3 to 20.");
            System.out.println("Qutting now.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Print the top triangle section of the christmas tree
        for (int i = 0; i < treeHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < treeHeight - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < (2 * i + 1); k++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        //Print the bottom rectangle section of the tree
        for (int c = 0; c <= (1 + (treeHeight / 5)); c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d <= (treeHeight / 3); d++) {
                System.out.print("");
            }
            System.out.printf("*");
        }

    }
}
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to get the proper input shape for the rectangle that would be awesome, I know I can center it with a simple printf once it is built properly.

Comment: Can you add the output?

Comment: What do you expect `print("")` to do?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to visualize what your result should be.

Example, `n = 8`, so base should be `1 + n/5 = 2` tall and `n / 3 = 2` adjusted to `3` wide.

```
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
   ***********
  *************
 ***************
       ***
       ***
```

Your code has the following problems:

- `print("")` is a meaningless statement. It does nothing.
- You don't print any leading spaces for indentation.
- You don't print `*` for a count equal to base width.
- You don't call `println()` so base height will definitely not work.

You got the tree part good, so you really shouldn't have problems with this. I won't give you the answer, but hopefully this visual example will help you do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

And if you make your for loop start at 0, then don't use a equal sign, as it will work 1 more time to what you expect

Answer (score 0):

You almost made it, just a couple comments about your code:

- In the last for you should have used < instead of <= like you did on the beggining
- You had clear the rules so you just needed to write them in your code, like I did in my code try to make it more clear, find the height and the width of the stump before writing it out
- In the inner for you should have printed out the * and in the outer for you just needed to print a new line

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  ```
      //User introduction 
      System.out.println("This program prints a \"Christmas\" tree. You "
          + "choose how big the tree will be (within reason)");

      // prompt for and get user input
      System.out.println("How tall should the top of the tree be?");
      int treeHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
      while (treeHeight < TREE_MINIMUM || TREE_MAXIMUM < treeHeight) {
          System.out.println("That's not a valid size.  I can only do trees "
              + "from 3 to 20.");
          System.out.println("Qutting now.");
          System.exit(0);
      }

      //Print the top triangle section of the christmas tree
      for (int i = 0; i < treeHeight; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < treeHeight - i; j++) {
              System.out.print(" ");
          }
          for (int k = 0; k < (2 * i + 1); k++) {
              System.out.print("*");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
      //Print the bottom rectangle section of the tree
      int stumpHeight = (1 + (treeHeight / 5));
      int stumpWidth;
      if ((treeHeight / 3) % 2 == 0) {
          //it is even add 1
          stumpWidth = (treeHeight / 3) + 1;
      } else {
          //it is odd keep it like that
          stumpWidth = (treeHeight / 3);
      }
      for (int c = 0; c < stumpHeight; c++) {
          //sorry for adding the spaces but I don't like the incomplete answers
          //centering
          for (int d = 0; d < treeHeight - stumpWidth/2; d++) {
              System.out.print(" ");
          }
          //adding stump
          for (int d = 0; d < stumpWidth; d++) {
              System.out.print("*");
          }
          //going to the next line
          System.out.println();
      }
  ```